# Angular 9 How to import HTML file as a string with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using  Angular 9.1.3 and Typescript 3.8.3.

I want to import html file as a raw string.

For the case:

```
import * as template from "./projects.page.html";
console.log("Template: ", template);
```

I'm getting error:

```
ERROR in src/app/features/projects/projects.page.ts:41:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './projects.page.html'.

41 import * as template from "./projects.page.html";
```

If I add `html.d.ts` file:

```
declare module "*.html" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/features/projects/projects.page.html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <div style="height: calc(100vh - 64px)">
```

Comment: If you just want to get the component's html in ts code, you can get it with ViewChild reference ex: ` @ViewChild('abc', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) htmlRef: ElementRef; htmlRef.nativeElement.innerHTML` should give you the component's html.

Comment: I don't want to include it into the DOM for reading later...

Comment: You will need raw-loader webpack for this, which will convert a text file into a javascript module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mention @htn in the comment - will need raw-loader webpack for this.

```
npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack
npm i -D raw-loader
```

Update angular.json

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
        "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
        "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
                "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
...

"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
            "path": "./webpack.config.js"
        },
        "browserTarget": "okwiki:build",
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Add `html.d.ts`:

```
declare module "*.html" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

And it works:

```
import template from "./projects.page.html";
console.log("Template: " + template);
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I fixed it using the html template inside a typescript file.

You could create a template.ts file like this:

```
const template = `
  <div> Your template here! </div> 
`;

export default template;
```

And you could simply import the file in this way :

```
import template from "./template";
```

Comment: Yep, this will definitely work but it's not what I'm looking for...